# ¿Como convertir un int a str en python de forma recursiva?

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo python este es el ejemplo del ejercicio

Definir la función deEnteroACadena tal que deEnteroACadena n es la cadena correspondiente al número entero n. Por ejemplo,

deEnteroACadena 1972 == "1972"

Comment: Bienvenida, por favor considera leer [ask] y de paso checar el [tour], te comento que para evitar el cierre de tu pregunta por ser amplia y no mostrar un punto de partida, entonces pudieras editar y agregar lo que llevas

Comment: con `str(1972)` o con `1972.__str___()`

Comment: Supongo que lo que quieres hacer es un bucle que transforme una lista de numeros int a str. Te dejo debajo la solución. (si no es eso, hazmelo saber)

Comment: ¿por qué de forma recursiva? ¿Es un enunciado de un problema de clase? No veo que el enunciado mencione nada de recursividad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de varias formas, te dejo unas cuantas:

#### 1. Bucle for

```
lista_int = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
lista_str = []

for numero in lista_int:
    lista_str.append(str(numero))

print(lista_str)
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

#### 2. List comprehension

```
lista_str = [str(numero) for numero in lista_int]

print(lista_str)
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

#### 3. Función Map

```
lista_str = list(map(str, lista_int))

print(lista_str)
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

Comment: Y ninguna de ellas responde al enunciado planteado, ya que no se trataba de recorrer lista alguna, sino simplemente de convertir un entero en cadena (o sea, un simple `str(dato)`). Supongo que de todas formas usar `str(dato)` no estará permitido, pues en el título pide hacerlo de forma recursiva.